# Allowing a certain range of dates dynamically in primefaces

Tags: jsf, events, date, primefaces

I have used maxdate and mindate to select the dates dynamically for two date fields(from date and to date) using the below code-

```
<p:calendar id="FromDate" value="#{controller.fromDt}" showOn="button" 
    maxdate="#{controller.toDt}" >
       <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="ToDate"></p:ajax>
    </p:calendar>

 <p:calendar id="ToDate" value="#{controller.toDt}" showOn="button"
     mindate="#{controller.fromDt}">
       <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="FromDate"></p:ajax>
    </p:calendar>
```

Everything seems to work fine if a date is selected. The restrictions are applied to the other dependent calendar. Like if **fromDate** is set, then restrictions are applied to the **todate**. But once the **fromdate** is deleted using backspace or delete, still the restrictions are there in **toDate** field.

I understand that when the date is deleted, then it is not a dateSelect event, but even trying to place a valueChange event won't work because valueChangeEvent is triggered only when the page is submitted.

Can someone suggest me an idea how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add another [p:ajax](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/ajax.html) with a change event.

```
<p:calendar id="FromDate" value="#{controller.fromDt}" showOn="button" 
  maxdate="#{controller.toDt}" >
   <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="ToDate"></p:ajax>
   <p:ajax event="change" update="ToDate"></p:ajax>
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: First I am sorry for this late reply. But Hatem, I am still unable to remove the restrictions from the other dependent calendar. As far as I know a change event will only be triggered if the form is submitted. But in this case I am not submitting any form, I just delete the date. That's it. Please rectify me if I am wrong.

Comment: the `p:ajax` would be triggered once the calender is changed, removed or modified the date (not via the selectionPanel). then it will update the other calender with the current value, so the attribute would be passed to the Validator. It's working fine in my Projects... @Manish

Comment: would you mark the question as correct and up voted, I don't know why it's down voted !

Comment: Even I tried to do it...But it says I am short of reputation. For voting up it requires 15 reputations. As I am new to StackOvetrflow, I don't have that many repo now...Sorry buddy. I will vote it up, once I reach 15.